# TFS 2013 work item change event listener is not working

Tags: plugins, tfs

I'm trying to listen workitem changes in TFS 2013. I created a c# project and build successfully this code below. Then dll located in tfs server:

[image: dll location]

I restart machine and I checkin a class in tfs for test with a work item. When I control tfs server there is no any Log folder created in C disk like code. TfsEventHandler project builded with .net framework 4.5

My queston is, why plugin is not working?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace TfsEventHandler
{
    public class WorkItemChangedEventHandler : ISubscriber
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return "WorkItemChangedEventHandler";
            }
        }

        public SubscriberPriority Priority
        {
            get
            {
                return SubscriberPriority.Normal;
            }
        }

        public EventNotificationStatus ProcessEvent(
            TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext,
            NotificationType notificationType,
            object notificationEventArgs,
            out int statusCode,
            out string statusMessage,
            out Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.ExceptionPropertyCollection properties)
        {
            statusCode = 0;
            properties = null;
            statusMessage = String.Empty;

            WriteLog("WorkItemChangedEventHandler1");

            try
            {
                if (notificationType == NotificationType.Notification && notificationEventArgs is WorkItemChangedEvent)
                {
                    WorkItemChangedEvent ev = notificationEventArgs as WorkItemChangedEvent;
                    int workItemId = Convert.ToInt32(ev.CoreFields.IntegerFields[0].NewValue);
                    WriteLog("WorkItemChangedEventHandler WorkItem " + ev.WorkItemTitle + " - Id " + workItemId.ToString() + " was modified");
                    EventLog.WriteEntry("WorkItemChangedEventHandler", "WorkItem " + ev.WorkItemTitle + " - Id " + workItemId.ToString() + " was modified");
                    
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
          
            return EventNotificationStatus.ActionPermitted;
        }

        public Type[] SubscribedTypes()
        {
            return new Type[] { typeof(WorkItemChangedEvent) };
        }



        public static void WriteLog(string strLog)
        {
            StreamWriter log;
            FileStream fileStream = null;
            DirectoryInfo logDirInfo = null;
            FileInfo logFileInfo;

            string logFilePath = "C:\\Logs\\";
            logFilePath = logFilePath + "Log-" + System.DateTime.Today.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") + "." + "txt";
            logFileInfo = new FileInfo(logFilePath);
            logDirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(logFileInfo.DirectoryName);
            if (!logDirInfo.Exists) logDirInfo.Create();
            if (!logFileInfo.Exists)
            {
                fileStream = logFileInfo.Create();
            }
            else
            {
                fileStream = new FileStream(logFilePath, FileMode.Append);
            }
            log = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
            log.WriteLine(strLog);
            log.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: TFS 2013 is a very old version of the server, how do you set events in tfs2013？ Did you encounter any errors when running this sample?

Comment: There is no any error related tfs in eventViewer/windowsLog or eventViewer/systemLog. What should I ckeck for "how do you set events in tfs2013" ?

Comment: You could try to share the screenshot about the settings.